# What is GdiVerticalFont used for?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fonts

So, I did a search and nothing pulled up.

Microsoft's definition of [GdiVerticalFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.gdiverticalfont.aspx) is vague:

> **true** if this Font is derived from a GDI vertical font; otherwise, **false**.

Huh. Really? So I'm thinking I shouldn't be messing with it; however...

Here it is, available for anyone to change, in the Visual Studio designer.

(FYI: I hacked this pic off another SO question)

[image]

I have only ever seen it set to FALSE.

I tried changing it to true, and noticed nothing.

What is this for?

Comment: It probably means that the font is [intended for vertical use](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2005/08/04/447759.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Raymond! But why post this as a comment?

Comment: And the link is dead.

Comment: Thanks for the note, @techtonik. New link: [GdiVerticalFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.gdiverticalfont.aspx)